# My Jquery Transit is Not working, What should I do

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I try to animate objects with the jquery plugin Jquery Transit : http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/
but it not working. so I want to coding like this https://codepen.io/sandrasofia/pen/pvbmNB

Questions are 1.My objects are not in the center and I need a blue color high as red box.
2. Why I can not run the Script?
Thanks
[image]
[image]

```js
var val0 = -10,
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 5,
    val3 = 10;

$(".fa").transition({ scale:1, opacity:0.5, y:val2 } );
$("h3").transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:0, y:val3 }, 300);

var bigIcon = $(".actionIcon");
$.each(bigIcon, function (index, value) {

  var fa = $(this).find(".fa"),
      h3 = $(this).find("h3");
      
    $(this).hover(function() {          
            fa.transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:1, y:val0 }, 200 );
            h3.transition({ scale:1, opacity:1, y:val1 }, 150);
        }, function() {
            fa.transition({ scale:1, opacity:0.5, y:val2 });
            h3.transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:0, y:val3 }, 300);
        }
    );
});
```

```css
.content{
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.iconPlay {
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.fa{
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.iconPlay ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}
.iconPlay li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.iconPlay h3 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: rgb(51, 3, 3); 
}

span {
  color: rgb(230, 24, 24);
}

.footer-basic {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding:30px 0;
}
.footer-basic .copyright {
  margin-top:15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      <div class=" iconPlay">
        <ul>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
                <h3>Love</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
              <h3>Love</h3>
          </li>
          <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
            <h3>Love</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
          <h3>Love</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
        <h3>Love</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
      <h3>Love</h3>
  </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.12/jquery.transit.js"></script>


<div class="footer-basic">
    <footer>
        <p class="copyright">2021</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you include ```jQuery``` library?

Comment: Also, these animations should probably just be included with ```css3```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not including `jQuery`  library, which is necessary to use this plugin.

You should however try and accomplish this with `css` only.

This one is just with `css`, you should probably tweak it where necessary, but it should give you a good start.

```css
.content{
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.iconPlay {
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.iconPlay .fa{
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.iconPlay li:hover .fa {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.2);
}
.iconPlay ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}
.iconPlay li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.iconPlay h3 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: rgb(51, 3, 3); 
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.iconPlay li:hover h3 {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1;
}

span {
  color: rgb(230, 24, 24);
}

.footer-basic {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding:30px 0;
}
.footer-basic .copyright {
  margin-top:15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="content">
      <div class=" iconPlay">
        <ul>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
                <h3>Love</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
              <h3>Love</h3>
          </li>
          <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
            <h3>Love</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
          <h3>Love</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
        <h3>Love</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
      <h3>Love</h3>
  </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="footer-basic">
    <footer>
        <p class="copyright">2021</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

This example includes your `jQuery` code.

```js
var val0 = -10,
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 5,
    val3 = 10;

$(".fa").transition({ scale:1, opacity:0.5, y:val2 } );
$("h3").transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:0, y:val3 }, 300);

var bigIcon = $(".actionIcon");
$.each(bigIcon, function (index, value) {

  var fa = $(this).find(".fa"),
      h3 = $(this).find("h3");
      
    $(this).hover(function() {          
            fa.transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:1, y:val0 }, 200 );
            h3.transition({ scale:1, opacity:1, y:val1 }, 150);
        }, function() {
            fa.transition({ scale:1, opacity:0.5, y:val2 });
            h3.transition({ scale:1.2, opacity:0, y:val3 }, 300);
        }
    );
});
```

```css
.content{
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.iconPlay {
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.fa{
  font-size: 35px;
  display: block;
}
.iconPlay ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 400px;
}
.iconPlay li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.iconPlay h3 {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: rgb(51, 3, 3); 
}

span {
  color: rgb(230, 24, 24);
}

.footer-basic {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding:30px 0;
}
.footer-basic .copyright {
  margin-top:15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="content">
      <div class=" iconPlay">
        <ul>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
                <h3>Love</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
              <h3>Love</h3>
          </li>
          <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
            <h3>Love</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
          <h3>Love</h3>
      </li>
      <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
        <h3>Love</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="actionIcon"><a href="#"><div class="fa"><span class="fas fa-heart"></span></div></a>
      <h3>Love</h3>
  </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.9.12/jquery.transit.js"></script>


<div class="footer-basic">
    <footer>
        <p class="copyright">2021</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Don't use the plugin that's work for me but the objects are not the center of site even have this code .iconPlay {
  text-align:center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}